# How to stop the form input type select data from erasing after PHP form validation?

Tags: php

I'm working on an e-commerce website, and I'm trying to validate a form using PHP.
So with my current code, the data doesn't get erased after I submit the form and if there is an error, all the data stays in the form and shows an error message, but I cannot make the same for the `select` options. What am I missing here?

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $error = false;
    if (empty($_POST["expMonth"])) {
        echo "<p class='errorMessage'> Month must be selected. </p>";
        $error = true;
    }
    if (!$error) {
        header("Location: confirmation.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<th><label for="expDate">Expiration Date</label></th>
  <td><select id="expMonth" name="expMonth"
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST["expMonth"])) echo "value='" . $_POST["expMonth"] . "' selected";
    ?>>
     <option disabled selected>Select Month</option>
     <option value="1">January</option>
     <option value="2">February</option>
     <option value="3">March</option>
     <option value="4">April</option>
     <option value="5">May</option>
     <option value="6">Jone</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: Instead of echoing the value into the input, you need to echo `selected` on the correct option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing the value into the input, you need to echo `selected` on the correct option. It should look something like this.

Also, valid HTML will only allow one option in a select to have the `selected` attribute. Your default option (`<option disabled selected>Select Month</option>`) might be causing a problem.

```
   <?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $error = false;
    if (empty($_POST["expMonth"])) {
        echo "<p class='errorMessage'> Month must be selected. </p>";
        $error = true;
    }
    if (!$error) {
        header("Location: confirmation.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<th><label for="expDate">Expiration Date</label></th>
<td><select id="expMonth" name="expMonth">
<?php
$months = [
    '1' => 'January',
    '2' => 'February',
    '3' => 'March',
    '4' => 'April',
    '5' => 'May',
    '6' => 'Jone',
];


foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
    $selected = '';
    if (isset($_POST["expMonth"]) && $_POST["expMonth"] == $key) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo "<option value='{$key}' {$selected}>{$value}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! I tried your code, but it shows repeated months in my select options... I added the screenshot as I can''t really explain it well..

Comment: Post all of your new code. It looks like you tried to mix my code and yours and you didn't erase the part of your old HTML code that was creating options.

Comment: Ahh!!! Sorry I found out why and fixed the problem!!! Thank you, one more question, somehow the foreach loop doesn't get the first value "January", why is this so?

Comment: I was missing a `>` after you select input, I updated my answer. Take a look.